# Getting a 403 error while using Axios in React

Tags: reactjs, axios

Hey great people of StackOverflow,

I'm creating a React app that uses the Google API, and I'm getting a 403 error when I use the search tool I've built, here's the following code:

```
import axios from 'axios'; 

const KEY = 'API KEY';

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3',
    params: {
      part: 'snippet', 
      maxResults: 5,
      key: KEY
  }
});
```

That's the API component to my React project, in my App.js, the callbacks look like this:

```
import React from 'react'; 
import SearchBar from './SearchBar';
import youtube from '../apis/youtube'; 

class App extends React.Component {
    onTermSubmit = (term) => {
    youtube.get('/search', {
    params: {
        q: term 
      }
    });
};
```

I thought it might have been one of the EventHandlers not going through with "submit" but that wasn't the case as I was able to look at the Dev Console and I isolated XHR requests in the Network, and this is what I got:

```
Request URL: http://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=5&key=MYAPIKEY
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 403 Forbidden
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you folks in advance.

Comment: What is the complete error message? 403 may mean that the url of your react application has not been whitelisted in the developer dashboard of the YouTube API. You need to specify the sources of requests, have you already gone this?

Comment: Hey Alexander thanks for your reply, there's two other things I receive after digging a bit deeper, a JSON file that reads (I cut it down a bit) `"SSL is required to perform this operation "code":403,"message":"SSL is required to perform this operation."}}` I'm thinking if I add `https://` that could solve the issue, but not sure. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Yeah adding `https://` seemed to work I'm now getting `Status Code: 200 OK` when trying to fetch via Axios now.

Answer (score 0):

friend!)
Yes, you're absolutely right — "submit" EventHandlers are okay as well as your app logic!

But for search-request we shouldn't use API KEY because everyone (even unauthorized user) can just search something in Google, cannot he? :)

So, in this term, you should remove the key property in your request:

```
import axios from 'axios'; 

const KEY = 'API KEY';

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3',
    params: {
      part: 'snippet', 
      maxResults: 5
  }
});
```

That's all, my friend!) Good luck to you!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30290495)